# How to get the minimal enclosed polyhedra in a Line framework (points connectivity lists)?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry, topology

Greetings all and thank you. I'm a Ph.D. candidate working on a force structure's 3D tessellation project and get stuck.

I've simplified the system into a set of lines linked together which formed a **Line-Framework** (points connectivity list). Now I want to get the tessellation of this Line-Framework in a set of minimal convex polyhedra without changing the connectivity of the points. Let me give an example for further description.

The Line-Framework is described in points pairs, e.g.**{{P1,P2};{P2,P3};{P2,P9}...}**, which can be drawn as follows. Each point *Pi* has coordinate details.(And all the lines are the same length.)
[image: Line-Framework]

And I want to have the convex set **{v1={P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8};v2={P9,P2,P3,P6,P7};v3={P10,P11,P1,P4,P5,P8}}**; *V=v1+v2+v3*. How can I workout the points set collections I need?

I've tried Delaunay triangulation but merging tetrahedra is complicated. THANKS!

The **Line-Framework** describes the system of a pack of spheres. Each $P_i$ is the center of the sphere, and $\{P_i,P_j\}$ means that the sphere $S_i$ contacts with $S_j$. The length of $\{P_i,P_j\}$ is $|P_i,P_j|=R_i+R_j$.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you considered computing the DCEL data structure, and then using some known convex-hull algorithm?

Comment: I'd like to know which properties of your example we can assume to hold in your application. In your example, the graph of your Line-Framework lies on the surface of the polyhedron that is the union of the minimal polyhedra you are looking for. Is this true in general? (this would be false if e.g. an edge between P1,P8 exists) Also, is the union of your polyhedra always bounded by a surface of genus 0? (in other words, is the Line-Framework always a planar graph, as in your example?) Finally, I'm not familiar with the term, "Line-Framework". Could provide a definition or reference?

Comment: If the assumptions I mention hold, then the faces of the polyhedra you look for are either a face of the graph of your Line-Framework, or bounded by a separating non-facial cycle of the Line-Framework. Additionally, each face of the line-framework occurs exactly once and each separating cycle occurs exactly twice. So one approach is to find all separating cycles of your Line-Framework and cut the graph at all of those cycles. Then the faces of all components that remain bound the minimal polyhedra.

Comment: @nirshahar About the convex-hull algorithm, I just know the two-dimensional algorithm in computational geometry gives the convex-hull to a set of points (points cloud). In three dimensions, I know little about the convex hull algorithm. It will be helpful if you can give me some links or examples. Thanks!

Comment: @Discretelizard Thanks for your reply. You've asked a very nice and sharp question. The term "Line-Framework" is a self-used word to describe the system of a pack of spheres. Each $P_i$ is the center of the sphere, and $\{P_i,P_j\}$ means that the sphere $S_i$ contacts with $S_j$. The length of $\{P_i,P_j\}$ $|P_i,P_j| = R_i + R_j$.

Comment: @Discretelizard If all the spheres are the same radii, the assumptions can be hold. But I also want to deal with spheres with different radius to get the void within the particles (not vary too much around 1cm~3cm), the split faces may not be a plane.

Comment: @SimonShi take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416861/how-to-find-convex-hull-in-a-3-dimensional-space as well as this explanation I found with a fast google-ing: http://algolist.ru/maths/geom/convhull/qhull3d.php

Comment: @nirshahar Thanks a lot! Qhull can just find A Convex Hull for all points in a set. I need to classify the points to different sets so that the algrithom could help. But classification is difficult also I need to sustain the connectivity of the points.

Comment: Is this close to what you want? Please see:  https://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1841&context=cstech

Comment: Also this CGAL package might be just what you need:  https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_decomposition_3/index.html

Comment: And could you please define the term "minimal convex polyhedron"? The word "minimal" requires explanations... Minimal among which polyhedra?

Comment: @HEKTO Thanks for your help! CGAL doc shows the method of Decomposition of Polyhedra by adding new edges and faces, which I don't want any other lines except the lines in "Line-framework". Because every line $\{P_i,P_j\}$ in the model has physical meanings - "sphere contacts". 
About the word "Minimal".  
1. $ v1+P9 = \{P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9\} $ is also an enclosed polyhedron but it can be divided into two convex polyhedron v1 & v2 without adding any other lines. 
2. $ v_new = v1-P_k , k \in {1,2 to 8}$ **$v_new$** can not be an enclosed polyhedron.

Comment: Your "Line-Framework" term can be replaced by more common term "Polygon Mesh" (please see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh). @Discretelizard in the comment above explained how to approach this mesh decomposition using "separating non-facial cycles". If you want to ask about 3D structures, induced by spheres touching, then your question needs to be reformulated.

Comment: @HEKTO Thanks for your patient instruction! I think I need to reformulate the question later. And I'll try searching "Polygon Mesh" and "mesh decomposition" first which are new terms to me.